# Java access to curl lib

Tags: java, curl

I just want to ask if java have access to the curl library? 
I have already tried the link below:
http://chimpler.blogspot.com/2009/03/logging-to-ebay-with-java-curl.html

I Just downloaded the CurlGlue.java because it is also missing in the archive.

when it comes to compilation part (`javac -classpath . se/haxx/curl/*.java`) below is the error:

```
private native int jni_setopt(int i, int j, CurlRead curlread);
                                            ^
symbol:   class CurlRead
location: class CurlGlue
se/haxx/curl/CurlGlue.java:48: error: cannot find symbol
private native int jni_setopt(int i, int j, CurlIO curlio);
                                            ^
symbol:   class CurlIO
location: class CurlGlue
se/haxx/curl/CurlGlue.java:74: error: cannot find symbol
public int setopt(int i, CurlRead curlread)
                         ^
symbol:   class CurlRead
location: class CurlGlue
se/haxx/curl/CurlGlue.java:79: error: cannot find symbol
public int setopt(int i, CurlIO curlio)
                         ^
symbol:   class CurlIO
location: class CurlGlue
```

.......

If any one knows where to get the complete curl-java-master? Kindly let me know the link.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, you need a hell of a lot more info in your question before we can help you... otherwise the answer is going to be "yes"... Please edit you question and add more info about what you are trying to do, add any relevant code you've tried, and what the errors were that you got. Add any relevant research you've done (to show us that you've done some, as well as so we don't duplicate your effort). In fact, read this article and use it to help you write a better question (you'll get help much quicker if you do): http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thanks for your advice Taryn East :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different implementations of cURL in Java. The original one is https://github.com/pjlegato/curl-java, but that's not complete. There's others like https://code.google.com/p/java-curl-jar/ that seem promising.

Keep in mind, most of what cURL does can be done in other ways through Java, cURL isn't always necessary. It might be easier to go a different route.

Comment: thanks leuan. I've already tried this link https://code.google.com/p/java-curl-jar/ and its not working.

Comment: Well sadly, short of non-cURL options there isn't a whole lot to be done in Java. There is no official cURL library for Java as far as I can find and most cURL libraries on code.google and github seem either in development or simply incomplete. If you could elaborate on your specific need we might be able to help you though.